# UML. How to illustatrate usage of external libraries?

Tags: java, uml

How to illustrate in UML dependency on external libraries, like Hibernate, Apache POI etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would normally represent this in an implementation diagram that shows the module (component) structure.  Simply put the external libraries on the diagram and stereotype them appropriately to make it clear that they are external dependencies.  Then use a "uses" dependency relation to indicate the parts of the system that depend on them.

For example, to use a trivially simple case ...

[image]

This shows two system modules (JAR files) with one dependent on the other, and one of them dependent on an external JAR file.   The stereotypes used to make the nature of the modules clear are custom stereotypes that I've created for this model (as UML doesn't come with such specific stereotypes in its meta-model).

Comment: In your case the "external" and "javajar" are custom stereotypes?

Comment: Yes they are.  I should have made that clear. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: what program did you use to illustrate this diagram? @Eoin

Comment: I used MagicDraw to create that diagram.